# How to mock a class in Jest

Tags: javascript, jestjs, mocking

I have the following JavaScript function (part of a class) which I want to test in Jest.

```
    static addPost(data){
    //write post details to json
    const allPosts = this.allPosts; //Get posts from json
    const newPostID = allPosts.length +1; // make new add for post

    const newPost = { id: newPostID, ...data }; //add new add to post
    allPosts.push(newPost); //add new post to all posts

    //writing the posts with the new posts to json
    const post = JSON.stringify(allPosts, null, 2);

    fs.writeFile('./json/data.json', post, (err) => {
        if (err) throw err;
    });
    return newPost;
}
```

This function reads from and writes to a JSON file. Is there a way I can test (using Jest) this without writing to the JSON file? I read about Jest mocking but I have no idea how to start. Anyone can help with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to find a solution to my question. The testing code is below.

```
describe('Mocking testing fs', () => {
    jest.mock('fs');
    it('Should add new post and return it', () => {

        jest.spyOn(fs, 'writeFile').mockImplementation();
        const result = Post.addPost(testData);
        expect(fs.writeFile).toHaveBeenCalled();
        expect(typeof result).toEqual('object');

        expect(result.id).toEqual(12);
        
    })
})
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).